# Check if user logged in using Google or Facebook

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

My app provides login with Google and Facebook using Firebase. How can I keep track if user logged in via Google or Facebook ? I need Do I need to store it somehow like using `SharedPreferences` or `FlutterSecureStorage` ?

Comment: I found out they have isSignedIn() methods, so that should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

When you login you get `response` and there is `providerId` in it:

[image]